# iframe not working on angularjs

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to get an iframe to work with AngularJS, but I don't know why it wont load my iframe src.

I have some angular double bracket variables, that I want to put at the end of the iframe src, but when I do it, I get a error.

The iframe code looks like this:

```
<iframe name="deltager" src="http://someurl.com/somefile.php?id={{item.id}}" frameborder="0" style="width: 100%; height: 45px !important;" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

It is the {{item.id}} that doesn't work.
I have tried to put a ordinary link, without the variable, and it works fine.

I tried to inspect the app with chrome inspect, and the error that i get is:

```
Error: [$interpolate:noconcat] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/$interpolate/noconcat?p0=http%3A%2F%2Fsomeurl.com%2Fsomefile.php%id%3D%7B%7Bitem.id%7D%7D
at Error (native)
at file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.min.js:37:417
at g (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.min.js:119:378)
at Pa (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.min.js:99:179)
at W (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.min.js:84:359)
at T (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.min.js:82:392)
at T (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.min.js:83:55)
at T (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.min.js:83:55)
at T (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.min.js:83:55)
at T (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.min.js:83:55)
```

Is there anyone who knows how I can get iframe src to work with angular variables.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using the **ng-src** attribute?

If the link is an external resource, you will need to configure the **$sce** service to trust the url.

```
<iframe ng-src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{item.id}}" ></iframe>
```

Comment: It is the same with ng-src. But I can try to look at the $sce service, but can you perhaps tell me where it is?

Comment: More information on the $sce service can be found at [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce)

A working sample can be found here [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/tYq22VjwB10WmytQO9Pb?p=preview)